# Rhapsody and Visual studio 2015, 2017, click on compiler errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, rhapsody

We  recently switched from `Visual Studio 2012` to `2015/2017`.

With 2012 double clicking on a compiler error navigated to the relevant model element or code.

This no longer works, neither with `Visual 2015` or `2017`, `Rhapsody 8.1.3` or `8.2.1`

Anyone know of a work around, or a relevant Rhapsody property?

Comment: VS won't jump to the error if it can't figure out where the error came from.  Does the source and line columns have data for the error in question?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from Yevo (Vladimer) on IBM developerworks Rhapsody forum
Due to changes from 2012 to 2015, needed to erase  a space before [:] in the following MSVC environment variable
Property ParseErrorMessage String "([^(]+)([)][:] (error|warning|fatal error"